How to create a custom notification bar in electron using React

Hello, I want to create a custom notification bar in Electron using React, similar to the one in the picture.
However, the Native Electron Notification API doesn't allow creating fully customizable notification bars.
I found a way to create a new BrowserWindow and load an HTML UI.
But this approach feels uncomfortable and doesn't support animations well.
Therefore, I want to find a better way to make a custom notification bar.
Please help me.
